# ¿Como obtener las filas de los datos mayores mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

#estimado mi idea de esta consulta es obtener los últimos registros de cada tracto_id_tracto. Quiero que se muestren los datos que salen pintado de un color azul opaco. hice un group by pero solo me muestras los primeros registro de cada tracto_id_tracto

```
SELECT id_seguro_obligatorio,DATEDIFF(vencimiento_seg_oblig,CURDATE()) AS contador,n_poliza,date_format(fecha_seg_oblig,'%d-%m-%Y') as fecha_seg_oblig , date_format(vencimiento_seg_oblig,'%d-%m-%Y') as vencimiento_seg_oblig,valor_seg_obligatorio,archivo_seg_oblig,tracto_id_tracto FROM seguro_obligatorio INNER JOIN tracto ON tracto.id_tracto=seguro_obligatorio.tracto_id_tracto
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este es un ejemplo mínimo de como obtener el último de un grupo:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  value INTEGER NOT NULL,
  id_tracto INTEGER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (1, 132, 1);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (2, 100, 1);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (3, 240, 2);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (4, 200, 2);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (5, 180, 3);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (6, 900, 4);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (7, 66, 4);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (8, 57, 4);


SELECT item1.*
FROM TEST item1 LEFT JOIN TEST item2
 ON (item1.id_tracto = item2.id_tracto AND item1.id < item2.id)
WHERE item2.id IS NULL;
```

A ti te queda ver como implementarlo en tu tabla

Comment: Funciona este script en verciones anteriores o iguales a mysql 5.7?

Comment: no... de hecho es algo nuevo que agregaron en MySQL 8.0. Pero puedo buscar un codigo compatible.

Comment: es que esa funcion es de SQL pero que bueno que la adaptaron a version a mysql8.0 @Keane1991 nos puedes detallar que version de Mysql tienes por favor

Comment: Entonces el script proporcionado por @Fedex7501 adecuado.

Comment: debería funcionarte, edita la pregunta con el nuevo script que estas corriendo; te recomiendo que pruebes con datos similares aquí [Mysql8](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=df039756e0f3ddb5a70ca3c1809147ee)

Comment: @keane1991 actualizé la respuesta con un código compatible con mysql 5.7. Lo puedes probar aquí: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3xzzw2e2b

Comment: @keane1991 honestamente no estoy seguro de como combinar las dos consultas. Y sin una tabla para probar está difícil.

Comment: @keane1991 en la tabla de la pregunta no hay ningun campo patente

Comment: @Fedex7501 ya lo solucione estimado :) muchas gracias por su aporte